# objc_retain EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access

I have been having a bit of a bug while testing on iOS 6 with my current iOS 5 app.

We have experienced a lock up on a method return for an innocuous method that internally used blocks, but not as properties. The issue is that calling the method works, so does every line of code within the method (including the block utilizing code)

I tried using [block copy] before calling the block, but there was absolutely no change.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

turns out the function definition of my code was declared in an internal interface and did not have a return type.

Here are some graphics to illustrate this issue.

The Initial Error

[image: The Initial Error]

The Stack Track

[image: The Stack Trace]

The Method in Question (isolated from self to determine the issue exact location)

[image: The Method in Question]

The Function Implementation (this is what is called, and returned)

[image: The Implementation Line]

The Definition in the Private Interface

[image: The Definition in the Private Interface]

I decided to look at the function call, and noticed it returning (id) rather than void

[image: Function returning (id)]

And Finally the only code change that alleviated this bug.

[image: Code Change]

**Explanation**

This bug reared its ugly head when my client called me saying our app does not run on ios 6

I was forced to download iOS 6 and Xcode 4.5 for testing this out.

I did indeed crash every time the app was run.

After hunting down this bug on stack overflow among other sites linked to by Google, I tried the block issue that some others are experiencing. And did a copy wherever I could to try to alleviate the issue of retained object falling off the stack.

I was not using block properties so I just called copy on the blocks themselves.

This did not help.

Finally with another developer going over it with me. I was stepping back and looking at it from another angle, and decided to try to determine what the heck was being retained.

It turned out the result of the function was being retained. And the only way I figured that out was to look at the value that auto complete showed me as the return type.

I knew the return type to be void, however it was telling me that the return type was id and that is what sparked the investigation into the method definition.

I hope this helps others that have this issue as I spent about 2 hours hunting it down and it turned out to be a semantic issue between a result type that should never have existed.

Comment: Didn't the compiler warn you that you were using an incompatible definition of `forceCurrentTime` in your implementation? When I try to reproduce your issue I get this message: `conflicting return type in implementation of 'forceCurrentTime': 'id' vs 'void'`

Comment: I'll report it as a bug on the LLVM project because ARC should prevent you from doing casts that can affect the retain/release mechanisms.

Comment: the compiler did not have anything about it. And I agree. ARC should be handling all the retain release scenarios. I am having other issues like this that are not connected to the missing return type, but the stack trace is <redacted> so I have nothing to go on.

Comment: to clarify it was not a cast as much as it was a bad definition of the method. However I would think that void could be treated like nil. but apparently I am incorrect.

Comment: No, `void` and `nil` are not the same. The return value of a `void` should be of 0 bytes, and the result of expanding it is undefined. This is obviously not an explicit cast, but the effect is the same as an implicit, all-permitive conversion: you can take a value of whatever type you want and turn it into a value of whatever other type. Clang should prevent it per [section 3.3.1 of the ARC specification](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#objects.restrictions.conversion). FYI, my bug report is [here](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=13845).

Comment: Thank you. Im hoping there is a swift update. Also thank you for the clarification. I guess I should have recognized that void is not nil but I see where you are coming from.

Comment: Fixing this problem will probably only involve turning the warning into an error. If you have other similar problems, I suggest that you clean your solution and rebuild it, then seek any similar problem and fix it.

Comment: I did not get any warnings. My method declaration was in a private interface, and it did not have a conflicting return type. the return type was completely omitted. I dont suppose you know if there is a simple explanation or tutorial describing how to update my llvm in xcode with the code or executable from llvm.org I would like to get an update in faster than apple will provide.

Comment: I just experienced the same bug. The funny thing is that my App was crashing on iOS 5 and 5.1 but not on 6.x. In my case, it was a subclass that overrode a method that was returning an object, but declared the overridden method as returning void (and didn't return anything itself). I didn't get any warnings either.

Comment: By the way, thanks for your detailed and very informative answer!

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Got this bug updating a old codebase to ARC/iOS7. It had a mismatched private interface declaration as well.

Comment: @zneak just a comment from the future - it's 2015 now and this issue appears to persist still today

Comment: @DanZimm, file a bug report too if you think it's important, duplicates are apparently how Apple prioritizes tasks.

Comment: @zneak the funny thing is when compiling for 64bit arm there was no issue :P

Comment: Thank you soooo much! This put me on the right track. I had a (void) method where in the method signature in the .h file I had forgotten to change the (id) return type to (void). Thank you! -- Erik

Comment: Thank you! The answer for me was also an incorrect block return type signature. :) would have taken me ages to find without your note!

Comment: I also had this issue but with a parameter type, not the return type.
Method definition: `- (void)plugin:(nonnull ATPeripheralPluginAnalog *)plugin didBeginCalibrationForPort:(ATPeripheralPort)port error:(nullable NSError *)error;` Method implementation: `- (void)plugin:(ATPeripheralPluginAnalog *)plugin didBeginCalibrationForPort:port error:(NSError *)error {` (Missing the type on the port param). I figured it out as the variables panel showed the type of `port` as `(id)`

Comment: This regex can help to find any similar issues in your project, it matches both return type missing and parameter type missing: `^- ?([^\( ]|.*?:[^\( ])`

Comment: When I create a mismatching header method and implementation it doesn't crash and it doesn't give a warning...It just works.  Is this something that can happen sometimes but not other times?

Comment: It may depend on the type difference between data types, it could be something that was fixed in later releases, it could be that you were not using or expecting to use the data type, it could be that the data types had the same memory consumption... There are a multitude of reasons why one thing would break and another would not. Glad to hear it worked out for you.